# Neither Event Viewer nor Task Scheduler work on my PC

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler, event-viewer

I have no idea why this is happening, but neither vent viewer nor task scheduler work on my PC.  I have posted this as one question because I bet it is related.

Thank you.

Here is the error I get when I try to run "Windows Event Log" service I get this error.
[image]

Here is a screen shot of the errors in Event Viewer and Task Scheduler.
[image]

Comment: Did you check the services list properly? There's **Windows Event Collector** which AFAIK is set to **Manual** by default, and **Windows Event Log**, which is set to **Automatic** by default.

Comment: @Karan Thank you, I think that helped my narrow down the problem.  I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Try deleting `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup` (might need to reboot into Safe Mode first), as detailed [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/cannot-start-windows-event-log-service-on-windows/e2c218ad-8637-49ee-8023-50eae0e4ddcb).

Comment: Thanks, I got to that same conclusion myself.  And it does work.  I had to do it from windows cd though, I couldn't do it while booted (even in safe mode!).  If you write up an answer with all of this I will vote it best answer.

Comment: Posted answer as requested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this seems to be corrupted (log) files and/or broken permissions.

### Fix 1 ([Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/cannot-start-windows-event-log-service-on-windows/e2c218ad-8637-49ee-8023-50eae0e4ddcb))

1. Reboot into **Safe Mode** using **msconfig**
2. Run **cmd.exe** as **Administrator**
3. Type `cd C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI` (assuming `C:\Windows` is where Windows is installed)
4. Type `ren RtBackup RtBackup2`
5. Use **msconfig** again to switch to normal boot mode
6. Reboot, verify that the `Windows Event Log` service has started and check the Event Viewer

Note: If Safe Mode does not work, you might need to do this from the Setup disc's System Recovery Command Prompt, or from any LiveCD/DVD/USB.

---

### Fix 2 ([Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-event-log-error-4201-instance-name-not-recognized))

1. Start Windows in **Safe Mode**
2. Open the `Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI` folder
3. Right-click on the `RtBackup` folder and choose `Properties`

   [image]
4. Click the `Security` tab, and click the `Edit` button

   [image]
5. Click `Add`

   [image]
6. Type `SYSTEM` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image]
7. Set `Full control` Permission to `Allow`

   [image]
8. Click `OK`, and then `Yes` when asked for confirmation

   [image]
9. Restart Windows in normal mode, verify that the `Windows Event Log` service has started and check the Event Viewer