# Task Scheduler Engine has stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

What could be the cause of the following error on Windows 7?
How can I debug the root cause of this reoccurring error?

[image]

The message reads:

```
Task Scheduler Engine has stopped working
Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
- Check online for a solution and close the program
- Close the program
```

Comment: Can't say for sure what the cause might be, but if you can't get it to work then *maybe* [this](http://superuser.com/questions/488237/neither-event-viewer-nor-task-scheduler-work-on-my-pc) will help in your case as well.

Comment: Basically the task sheduler crashed. This could be caused by real bug in the software, corrupted files, virus or network attack. Could you run a virus scan and `sfc /scannow` and report the results. Also, could you describe how often does this happend and the circumstances when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Open the Start menu
2. Type `cmd` into the search field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a command prompt
3. Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
   ```

Comment: Could you write a few words explaining what this does?

Answer (score -1):

I found this to explain the bcdedit command:

> Data Execution Prevention (DEP) is security feature that first
>   introduced in Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and is included in
>   Windows XP Tablet PC Edition 2005, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1
>   (SP1) and Windows Vista, plus future operating system. DEP is intended
>   to prevent an application or service from executing code from a
>   non-executable memory region. DEP is enforced by hardware technology
>   that detects code that is running from the default heap and the stack
>   and raises an exception to terminate the process when execution
>   occurs, and software-enforcer that prevent malicious code from taking
>   advantage of exception-handling mechanisms in Windows. In short, DEP
>   perform additional checks on memory to prevent malicious code or
>   exploits from running on the system by shut down the process once
>   detected.
>
> However, Data Execution Prevention may accidentally shut down
>   legitimate process from valid applications or services, particularly
>   third-party installers used by software developers that release their
>   products for download through the Web, or software programs that are
>   less commonly used. To make thing worse, DEP normally does not or
>   fails to display or show any warning or information or acknowledgment
>   message prompt that can let you know that DEP has shut down a process,
>   thus causing you unaware of the reason why your setup file cannot run,
>   or why your computer cannot start a service and etc.
>
> Good news is that you can disable or turn off Data Execution
>   Prevention (DEP) globally in Windows Vista. To stop the DEP
>   protection, launch an elevated command prompt shell with
>   administrative priviledges and credentials (log on to Windows Vista
>   with a user account with administrator rights, and then right click on
>   Command Prompt icon and select “Run as Administrator, or turn off
>   UAC). Then execute the following command:
>
> bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff
>
> If you regret your decision and now wants to enable or turn back on
>   the DEP protection for your Windows Vista, simply use the following
>   command instead:
>
> bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOn